# Using IDA to find pointer passed to procedure

Tags: ida, binary-analysis

Loading the source into IDA, I have this function:

[image]

According to the [source for Lua](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lapi.c.html), this function should be passed a pointer to the Lua_State struct:

```
LUA_API int lua_gettop (lua_State *L) {
  return cast_int(L->top - L->base);
}
```

I'm currently trying to figure out what pointer is being passed to this procedure (In this case `arg_0`). I can attach a breakpoint and it correctly breaks, but how would I find the associated `.data` location for where it's stored?

Comment: Hint: Press H key upon `ebp+arg_0`.